# Get date value in html5 using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I get this error "Cannot read property 'value' of null", please help to sort this out.I am trying to get the date values and passing to php. Thanks.

```
<form>
<label for="fromDate">From : </label><input id="from" type="date" id="fromDate" value=""></input>
<label for="toDate">To : </label><input id="to" type="date" id="toDate" value=""></input>

<input type="submit" value="submit"></input>
</form>
<input type="button" onclick="makeAjaxCall();return false;" value="Click to get data"></input>

<script>
function makeAjaxCall() {
    var frm = document.getElementById('fromDate').value;//$('#fromDate').datepicker("getDate");

    var to = document.getElementById('toDate').value;//$('#toDate').datepicker("getDate");
    var postDate ={
        "dateFrom" : frm,
        "dateTo" : to   
    };


  $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:'test.php',
            data: postData,
            success: function(responseData) {

                     //someCode
                   }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an input with two id's try using just one

```
<input type="date" id="toDate"
```

Instead of:

```
<input id="to" type="date" id="toDate"
```

Comment: everyone has his days, don't call yourself like that

Answer (score 1):

Use a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/). Some of your elements have multiple `id` attributes. This is not allowed and is the cause of your problem.

(You probably intended to use a `name` attribute for the first `id` attribute in both cases)